# How to select specific fields in elasticsearch-dsl python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using elasticsearch dsl to search on elasticsearch : https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

How can i filter specific fields while making a search query:

I know its supported in elasticsearch:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-fields.html

Just dont know how to do the same in Elasticsearch-dsl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you have your `Search` object you can call the `.fields()` function on it and specify which fields you want to return:

```
s = search.Search()
s = s.fields(["field1", "field2"])
...
```

It's not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but you can see the `fields` function in the [source for the `search.py` file](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/62898c1737c44a93c933285ad891267c5ed0a306/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py#L306) and some [test cases for the `fields` function](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/62898c1737c44a93c933285ad891267c5ed0a306/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_search.py#L352)

*UPDATE*

From ES 2.x onwards, the `fields()` method has been renamed to `source()`

Comment: Thanks man. can you help me with this as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799486/how-to-enable-track-scores-in-elasticsearch-dsl-python, thanks again :)

Comment: you can also do all fields with (["_all"]) which is useful.

Comment: @ user1903663 `fields: _all` won't work if `_all` is disabled, have you tried it?

Comment: It looks like `.fields()` method was changed to `.source()` in version 2.x of elasticsearch-dsl [(link)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/a455fdd51a8cfa9f4b9ce7733f7a91b5e5d41ca1/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py#L387)

Comment: @AmiHollander are you talking about `.fields()` our `.source()`?

Comment: this makes no sense fields and source are two different things in ES.

Comment: @JasonGenX Look at the date of the question and the comment, so many versions came inbetween, probably another answer is more accurate by now

Answer (score 4):

In elasticsearch-dsl version 6.x.x `fields()` is deprecated and result with exception.

use `source(fields=None, **kwargs)` in order to `projection` columns

e.g.

```
s = Search()
s = s.source(["field1", "field2"])
s = Search()
s = s.source(include=['obj1.*'], exclude=["*.description"])
s = Search()
s = s.source(include=['obj1.*']).source(exclude=["*.description"])
```

Answer (score 0):

i use that for all fields :

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q, Search
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 

client = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')

q = Q("multi_match", query='STRING_TO_SEARCH', fields=['_all'])
result = Search(index='YOUR_INDEX').using(client).query(q).execute()
```

or for specific fields :

```
fields=['name',]
```